# Unable to sideload outlook add-in

Tags: npm, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, npm-start

I am building a outlook add-in and trying to sideload the add-in to outlook web application.

I am using npm and yeomangenerator as instructed in this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=yeomangenerator

Everything seems to be fine until I do "npm start" when I get following error -

Sideloading the Office Add-in...

Error: Unable to start debugging.

Error: Unable to sideload the Office Add-in.

Error: Sideload is not supported.

Screenshot of the error is as shown - 
[image]

I have already installed the ssl certificate as well.

I am on windows 10.

Please let me know in case any other info is required.

Comment: Could you see if this helps on sideloading in Outlook? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The article you shared talks about sideloading from outlook. I am able to upload the manifest after per the article shared by you without any issues but the taskpane doesn't appear as expected after uploading the manifest. Also, I have now added the screenshot of error in description when I do "npm start" in cmd. 
I am following the tutorial shared in the description of my question.

Comment: Understood. For Outlook, after you sideload to install the addin (which you have done), you need to keep the local dev server running.  The source url's for your addin should be pointing to localhost, which is the local dev server.  Could you try "npm run dev-server"?  What is the error you see when you open the taskpane?

Comment: I was able to sideload ok according to the side loader page but I never saw my actions. I struggled for many hours on why. It turns that under settings you may need to turn on which "actions" are available in your read/compose pane. My add-in was listed but not checked, hence it was not enabled to be shown. Once I enabled my add-in in the settings page to be shown, it showed up and ran fine.